# Yii2 PHP Try Catch not triggering in view index.php

Tags: php, exception, yii2, try-catch

I have the following code in a view page index.php file.

```
try {
    $canDelete = (boolean)CallLogUsers::find()->where(['userid' => Yii::$app->user->identity->getId()])->one()->getAttribute('canDelete');
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    $canDelete = false;
}
```

The error produced is ***Call to a member function getAtrribute() on null*** .

An exception is produced but my catch doesn't trigger.  The error is getting trapped in the Yii2 View.php file and thrown on to the ErrorHandler.php file which finally exits.

I know what is causing the error and I just want to set the necessary variable to false and continue.
Is there a way that I can trap this error or do I have to rewrite code ?

Comment: You need `catch (\Throwable $ex)`, since `Call to a member function x on null` will produce `Error` instead of `Exception`. But you should probably check `one()` result instead of relying on exceptions - you may hide bugs in this way, since exceptions could be thrown for other reason an you just ignore it with current approach.